# Mapping different ServerPath to different DocumentRoot with the same address

Tags: apache-2.2, documentroot

I am using an Apache server within an intranet to give access to reports. I want, with the same servername, to map a server path to a different documentroot that happens to be a file share.

Is this feasible with a VirtualHost ?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerPath /path1
    DocumentRoot remote-share
    ServerName servername
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerPath /path2
    DocumentRoot remote-share
    ServerName servername
</VirtualHost> 

<Directory /path1>
    Options Indexes
</Directory>

<Directory /path2>
    Options Indexes
</Directory>
```

In this case, path1 works but overrides path2 therefore path2 never works - probably because it's the same virtual host - but again, I need to have the same address, just different sub-folders mapped to different DocumentRoots.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `mod_alias` and the `Alias` directive

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName servername
  DocumentRoot /dummy/path
  Alias /path1 /path/to/mounted/fs/path1
  Alias /path2 /path/to/other/fs/path2
</VirtualHost>
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias for details.